# Mechanism for marking messages "read" in our chat module in our rail's app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chat

We have a chat feature in our rails app where users can talk to each other.

This is done using Actioncable, and a basic `messages` and `inboxes` schema structure, where:

- Each unique conversation between 2 participants has its own `inbox_id`, and all messages sent by users to another user reside in that `inbox_id`.
- In the `messages` table, which holds the records of every message, we have a `read` column (which is currently unused).

We want to implement a way for our system to know if messages have been read by a specific user, but we're not entirely sure what the best method to facilitate this might be. We're unsure on how we should go about designing this exactly.

Comment: A join table - users -> user_messages -> messages.

Comment: I think you can add `read_user_ids` into `messages` table and stores user's id who read into an array. After that you can easily retrieve by [Rails's serialize](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize)